# Actionscript 2: Check if one of many radio buttons is equal to its slot an array?

Tags: flash, actionscript

In Flash I have a page with a total of 48 radio buttons. It is a question with 48 possible answers, but the question is different each time and only one answer can be correct to each question. What I need to do is to check if RadioButton1 is active when question 1 is active, and so on for all 47 questions. I get the question by doing this;

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+47-0))+0;
question.text = lander[i];
```

question.text is a text field which takes on the value of a random string in the array lander, which contains all of the possible questions. Now I need a way to find out which of the 47 radio buttons is active and match it with it's answer to find out if it is correct or not, but I've got no idea how to call the name of a radiobutton based on a variable.. or if there is another, better solution.

Appreciative of all help!
/J

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the radioButton states in a loop. I sent you the sample code. `checkAnswer()` func is your solution.

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+47-0))+0;
question.text = randomNumber;

var f:Sprite = new Sprite();

function init(){
    for(var i=0;i<48;i++) {
        var d:myRadioMc = new myRadioMc();
        f.addChild(d);
        d.x = (i % 8) * 60;
        d.myClip.label = i;
        d.name = "myRadio"+i;
        d.y = Math.floor((i / 8)) * 40;
    }
    f.y = 140;
    f.x = (stage.stageWidth -500)/2;
    this.addChild(f);
    checkAnswer();
}

function checkAnswer(){
    for(var i=0;i<48;i++) {
        var myClipLabel = f.getChildByName("myRadio"+i)
        if(myClipLabel.myClip.label == randomNumber){
            myClipLabel.myClip.selected = true;
        }
    }
}

init();
```

I added sample fla too. Hope it helps

[FLA](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53894534/question.fla)

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, I completely forgot to, but your code helped me immensely! Thank you!

Comment: if it helps vote up and the others can see it is working! ;) Happy coding